# Ordering by name in item-designer not possible anymore in Servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I am using the Item-Designer in Servicenow. (running fuji)
We have a test environment and a production environment running on the same patchlevel.
While on my testing-environment I can sort the items by name, I can't do that on prod.
Screenshot of test:
[image: test]

Screenshot prod, please see that the Name field is greyed out.

[image: prod]

There must be a setting somewhere, but I am unable to find it.
What else may lead to this effect? Any help is up-voted, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you right-click the column header (or click the little arrow next to the "Name" column header label), does it have a "Sort A-Z" context menu option? If so, is it grayed-out as well? You can compare the attributes on the dictionary entry for that particular field to see if there are any notable differences.

Comment: hey joey, that part is greyed out, yes. What do you suggest? Dictionary hmm, never seen it :)

Comment: Go to the sys_dictionary table, search for Table name="the table you're looking at" and Column/Element name="the column you're looking at" and look at the attributes field. You'll need to be an admin to actually see this.

Answer (score 1):

Since the field "Name" on Item Designer is a translated field I think it maybe has something to do with this:

> Starting with the Fuji release, you have the option to turn off
>   sorting, starts with, and ends with operations for translated fields
>   by setting the No Sort internationalized [no_sort_i18n] dictionary
>   attribute to true.

https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Using_Translated_Fields#Disabling_Unsupported_Operations_on_Translated_Fields

Community post about this attribute says:

> Unfortunately you cannot edit Field Class records as it requires
>   "maint" access, so only ServiceNow personnel can do it for you. But,
>   out of box the attribute is not set, so in your case maybe it was set
>   on purpose at one point in time?

https://community.servicenow.com/thread/212006

I can confirm that on our Fuji Instance this field is also not sortable, but on our new Helsinki Instance it can be sorted. So maybe it could also be a restriction of Fuji.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience on that. We are about to upgrade soon, so I will simply wait :)